# Ordered List with Nested Counters but not always

Tags: css, nested, html-lists

I would need to show ordered lists with numbering type 1.1 with sub-lists with simple or unordered numbering (point). In description what I would like to appear

This is how I would like it to come and the code I tried with.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol.subnum li {
  display: block;
  color: #666666;
}

ol.subnum li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
}

ol.nosub li:before {
  counter-increment: item;
}

ul.subpoint li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<ol class="subnum">
  <h2>
    <li>Voce 1</h2>
  <ol class="subnum">
    <li>Test 1.1</li>
    <li>Test 1.2
      <ol class="subnum">
        <li>Test 1.2.1
          <ol class="nosub">
            <li>Test 1.</li>
            <li>Test 2.</li>
            <li>Test 3.</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>Test 1.2.2</li>
        <li>Test 1.2.3</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Test 1.3</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
  <h2>
    <li>Voce 2</h2>
  <ol class="subnum">
    <li>Test 2.1 </li>
    <li>Test 2.2
      <ul class="subpoint">
        <li>Test point</li>
        <li>Test point</li>
        <li>Test point</li>
        <li>Test point</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Test 2.3</li>
  </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Thank you for suggestions

This the result of the code [1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbjyy.png

Comment: in the end, it is a list and a headline has nothing to do inside a list. Rather use CSS to make the main list point bold and larger.